# is there an easy way to design html handlebars templates

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I'm looking for a simple way to create some static html page designs but using handlebars partials to ease the handover to the developer. i.e. create

```
index.html
 sidebar.html
 main.html
 product.html
 product_stub.html
```

and so on. Then a simple way to build up the pages so I can see them in Chrome:

index.html:

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div class="sidebar">{{ include sidebar.html }}</div>
<div class="main">{{ include main.html }}</div>
</body>
```

main.html:

```
{% for i in 0 to 10 %}
{{ include product_stub.html }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then product_stub.html might look like:

```
<div class="product-stub">
  <h2>Product Name</h2>
  <p>some lipsum text...</p>
</div>
```

Then ideally the developer could take these same files, add in the magic - then the designer could edit to tweak the design..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble), it's specifically for this purpose.

Comment: This looks to be a good option. We created a simple "load" handlebars helper that will load in a template - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

We created a "load" handlebars helper that loads in a template:

```
  cache = {}
  template = (name) ->
    t = cache[name]
    if t?
      return t

    raw = null
    $.ajax
      url: "/static/templates/#{ name}.hbs"
      async: no
      type: 'GET'
    .done (text) ->
      raw = text
    .fail (err) ->
      if window.appdebug
        # if app is running in "debug" mode, fallback to possible design
        # template
        url = "/static/design/#{ name }"
        url = url + '.hbs' if not url.match(/\.hbs$/)
        $.ajax
          url: url
          async: no
          type: 'GET'
        .done (text) ->
          raw = text

    if not raw?
      throw "Cannot fetch template #{ name }"

    t = Handlebars.compile(raw)
    cache[name] = t
    t

  Handlebars.registerHelper "load", (name, ctx) ->
    new Handlebars.SafeString(template(name)(ctx))
```

Then in debug mode I can have a template that does this:

```
<div class="container content">
{{load "common.breadcrumbs"}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="main">
            {{load "product.edit.maindetails"}}
            ...
```

So we can then see a whole page split up into handlebars templates by the designers that's easy to add in the rest of the HBS code by the devs.